# Stack: use the pedantic flag by default on a particular project

Tags: stack, haskell-stack

I would like to build a project always using the `--pedantic` flag. Right now I'm using the

```
stack build --pedantic
```

command. But I would like to use this flag always for this project (thus, not globally). Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, pedantic pretty much just means to build with --ghc-options "-Wall -Werror".  So, in stack.yaml you can do that with:

`ghc-options:
  "*": -Wall -Werror`

In the future, `--pedantic` may do more than that, see https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1323 and https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3166 .  At that point it may become an option in `stack.yaml` configuration.